# asp.net listview select onmouseover

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to highlight a whole row of a listview when you mouse over it?
For example if you hover over one row, the row's background colour changes.
I asume it is the onmouseover attribute of tr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable using, jQuery try this:

```
$(function(){
$("tr").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');;
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');;
    });
});
```

**Updated:**

Add a class to your "tr" tag
Eg.:

```
<tr class="trOnHoverChange"></tr>

$(function(){
$(".trOnHoverChange").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');;
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');;
    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine also: onmouseover="this.style.background='Red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='#222222'" if applied to ItemTemplate tr and to AlternatingItemTemplate

Answer (score -1):

I found this which is similar to your question and will probably point you in the right direction:

[ASP.NET Gridview: Highlighting rows on mouse over then updating the highlighted rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552963/asp-net-gridview-highlighting-rows-on-mouse-over-then-updating-the-highlighted)

EDIT

Just found this, which sounds like what you are doing now.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1450332.aspx

Comment: Not exactly, listview works in a totally different way than gridview. I know for gridview it is a lot easier but I need to use advanced formatting hence the reason to use listview. I believe I might have it, it might only be a matter of setting background colour onmouseover and then onmouseout

Comment: fair enough, i did something similar once, but its a long time ago so I cannot really remember.